# What machine learning algorithms supported with spark mllib and does not supported with mahout and vise versa?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, apache-spark-mllib

I want list of ml algorithms that supported with spark mllib and does not supported with mahout and list of ml algorithms that supported with mahout and does not supported with spark mllib thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [page](https://spark.apache.org/mllib/) gives a good overview. It lists all the supported algorithms. If an algorithm is not shown there, you could assume it is not supported.

Classification: 
logistic regression, 
naive Bayes,...

Regression: 
generalized linear regression, 
survival regression,...
Decision trees, 
random forests, 
and gradient-boosted trees

Recommendation: 
alternating least squares (ALS)

Clustering: 
K-means, 
Gaussian mixtures (GMMs),...

Topic modeling: 
latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)
Frequent itemsets, 
association rules, 
and sequential pattern mining